# How to pass variables by reference in R?

Tags: r

I would like to ask how I can overwrite the variables `v` and `ind` in the following function:

```
 repcomb <- function(v,n,ind)
{
   k <- length(v)
   if(ind == 0)
   {
      for (i in 1:k) v[i] <- 1
      ind <- 1
      return
   }
   for (i in k:1) 
   {
      if(v[i] != n) 
      {
         for (j in k:i) v[j] <- v[i] + 1
         return
      }
   }
   ind = 0
}
```

What is the easiest way for updating `v` and `ind`?

Comment: 1) What are you _really_ trying to do? 2) `i+1:k` parses as `i + (1:k)`; you probably meant `(i + 1):k`.

Comment: Thanks. It is a really simple-minded implementation of the for loop. Since the only realistic interpretation of i+1:k is (i+1):k, therefore I don't understand why it has been so written by the authors.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: I would like to generate all the combinations with repetitions of cardinality binomial(n+k-1,k).

Comment: By the way, why is it important?

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way:

```
repcomb <- function(v,n,ind)
{
  k <- length(v)
  if(ind == 0)
  {
    for (i in 1:k) v[i] <- 1
    ind <- 1
    return(list(v=v, ind=ind))
  }
  for (i in k:1) 
  {
    if(v[i] != n) 
    {
      for (j in i+1:k) v[j] <- v[i] + 1
      v[i] <- v[i] + 1
      return(list(v=v, ind=ind))
    }
  }
  ind = 0
  return(list(v=v, ind=ind))
}

res <- repcomb(1:5, 4, 2)
v <- res$v
ind <- res$ind
```

Comment: Thank you! Did I misunderstand something? I have implemented a calling function, but there is some error in running. The output of the rep function should contain the vectors "1 1 1", "1 1 2", "1 2 2", and "2 2 2".

    rep <- function()
    {
      n <- 2
      v <- vector(mode = "integer", length = 3)
      ind <- 0
      repeat
      {
        rp <- repcomb(v,n,ind)
        v <- rp$v
        ind <- rp$ind
        if(ind == 0) break
        print(v)
       }
    }

Comment: actually you have multiple return statements in your function, so you need to return from multiple places, alternative is to just return from one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back the value of a parameter set inside a function, you can use `eval.parent(substitute(val<-new_val))`, for example:

```
f_sqr <- function(val){
     new_val <- val^2
     eval.parent(substitute(val<-new_val))
}
```

If you call it:

```
val <- 5
f_sqr(val)
val
#[1] 25
```

Please bear in mind that you should not change the value of the parameter inside the function, instead, you copy it to a new variable, do what you want to do in your code and finally set the value of new variable into your parameter variable as it is the case inside the function.

For your own function, this is what you have to do for your first `if`:

```
repcomb <- function(v, n, ind)
{
   k <- length(v)
   if (ind == 0)
   {
      new_v <- v
      for (i in 1:k) new_v[i] <- 1
      # ind <- 1
      new_ind <- 1
      eval.parent(substitute(ind<-new_ind))
      eval.parent(substitute(v<-new_v))
   }
}
```

Then if you call it, you will get the changes back:

```
v <- 1:5
n <- 3
ind <- 0
repcomb(v, n, ind)
v
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
ind
#[1] 1
```

Correspondingly, the other part can be changed to meet what you want.

Comment: Please try to avoid this programming pattern, it is not always safe and is not a good programming style. In this situation you can easily return new values in a list as suggested by the other response, which leads to much cleaner code. In some special cases you could also pass an environment (environments can be modified in place), this may in some cases lead to better performance, it is safe, but not very readable either.

Comment: @TomasKalibera It's not how I'd code it, it's rather what OP seemingly wants.